# Convert NSString with unicode characters into valid HTML

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, unicode

I am getting a string from an API that has anchor tags in it, so I am creating an `NSAttributedString` from it, and displaying it in a `UITextView` so I can support tappable links.

The problem is that the incoming string isn't valid HTML, so it has unescaped unicode characters in it. Things like:

- HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS Unicode: U+2026, UTF-8: E2 80 A6
- EM DASH Unicode: U+2014, UTF-8: E2 80 94

While I could deal with those specific cases, I'm concerned about any other unicode characters that come in, that I don't currently know about.

Example:

```
NSString *fromAPI = @"Reagan \U2014 saying";
NSDictionary *options = @{NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute : NSHTMLTextDocumentType};
NSData *data = [fromAPI dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:NO];
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data options:options documentAttributes:nil error:nil];
```

This renders in the UITextView as: [image]

How do I get it to render the em dash and other unicode properly?

Comment: So you want to be able to display the actual unicode characters in general without having them converted to something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found it, it looks like HTML won't render unicode unless you add this into the `<head>`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score -1):

What I was going to suggest (if I've understood the question correctly) was to use a regex or something to add the escape character `\U0000FE0E` or just `\UFE0E` to the end of all unescaped unicode characters, e.g.:

```
NSString *fromAPI = @"Reagan \U2014 saying";
NSString *convertedFromAPI = @"Reagan \U2014\UFE0E saying";
```

But I think what you are doing at the moment, makes more sense.

Comment: Adding escaping didn't fix it, I tried. Adding the meta tag to the head, does.